# Extracting the value from a Map given the key

Tags: angularjs

I have this map returned as JSON

```
"notificationData":[{"key":"origin","value":"ABC"},{"key":"destn","value":"XYZ"},{"key":"flt","value":"450"},{"key":"date","value":"10/14/2015"}]
```

currently i have this logic in angular to fetch the value for each key - is there a better way to directly access each key?

```
for(var notifydata = 0; notifydata < notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData.length; notifydata++)
{
                if(notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].key == 'origin')
                {
                                $scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.origin = notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].value
                }
                else if(notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].key == 'destn')
                {
                                $scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.destination = notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].value
                }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to map specific keys :

The main problem with your code is that you browse the whole notificationData array even if the searched objects come first.

In ES6, you will be able to use Array.prototype.find() to get the specific objects you need. For now, your `for` loop probably is the best way, however you should stop iterating when you have all your keys, either by adding a condition to your for or by using `break` :

```
for(
    var notifydata = 0;
    notifydata < notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData.length && (angular.isUndefined($scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.origin) || angular.isUndefined($scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.destination));
    notifydata++
) {
    if(notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].key == 'origin')
        $scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.origin = notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].value
    else if(notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].key == 'destn')
        $scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.destination = notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].value
}
```

or

```
for(var notifydata = 0; notifydata < notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData.length; notifydata++) {
    if(notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].key == 'origin')
        $scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.origin = notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].value
    else if(notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].key == 'destn')
        $scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.destination = notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData[notifydata].value
    if (angular.isDefined($scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.origin) && angular.isDefined($scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData.destination))
        break;
}
```

---

If you want to map all keys :

you should use Array.protoype.map() or Array.prototype.forEach() for cleaner code :

```
$scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData = {}
notificationMockdata[notify].notificationData.forEach(function(data) {
  $scope.notificationContent[notify].notificationData[data.key] = data.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to access directly, because your map-design requires to take a look on each object of the array. It's also possible to have multiple entries. A normal map in json is an object and looks like:

```
{
   'key1':'value1',
   'key2':'value2',
   'key3':'value3'
}
```

Maybe it's possible for you to change the serialization?